# jQuery Animate topbar

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have a top navBar that I need to go up when I click it.

```
    var foo = false
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".topBar").click(function(){
        findOut();
    });
});
function up()
{
    $(".topBar").animate({height:5},"slow");
}
function down()
{

    $(".topBar").animate({height:30},"slow");
}
function findOut()
{
    if (foo===true)
    {
        down();
        up =  false;
    }
    elseif (foo===false)
    {
        up();
        up = true;
    }
}
```

And before you ask, yes I do have the jQuery file installed.

Here is my website: learntc.net The very top bar.

Comment: `elseif(up===false)` You're missing a space, it should be `}else if(){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you consider doing:

```
  $("#topBar").click(function()
    {
        $(this).slideToggle()
    });
```

that will make your bar go up or down without the need to use a flag.

[docs](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/)

If you don't want to slide it all the way, your code looks fine except for a missing whitespace in `elseif(up===false)`.

If you try it on your site you'll see that the text is still visible even when you set the height to 5px, I recommend you add a `overflow:hidden` so it can remain hidden

**EDIT** 
Working code:

```
var up = false
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(".topBar").click(function(){
            findOut();
        });
    });
    function upFunc()
    {
        $(".topBar").animate({height:5},"slow");
    }
    function down()
    {

        $(".topBar").animate({height:30},"slow");
    }
    function findOut()
    {
        if (up===true)
        {
            down();
            up =  false;
        }
        else if (up===false)
        {
            upFunc();
            up = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, but I can't have it slide in all the way.

Comment: then the only thing that I can see it's that you're missing a space after the `else`

Comment: I fixed that, and it still does not work.. Ahh the life of a coder. xD

Comment: The `elseif` problem is still there. I'll edit the answer with the code I've just tried in your page and it worked for me (also adding the `overflow:hidden`)

Comment: Thanks soo much! I am used to Lua where elseif is one word. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are redefining the up variable to equal the up() function.
Maybe change to:

```
var isup = false;
```